# Is there a way to set the local time, which may be different than the server's time, in an ASP.NET MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, app-config

I have an MVC3 application the displays the current time locally, but displays the servers time when uploaded to hosting. Is there any way in the app.config or the web.config that I can set my local time to display once my app is uploaded to the server?

UPDATE:I'm looking for a way to do this globally without going back and changing the code for every time I reference DateTime. It seems a little impractical to not be able to set the time for the application globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set timezone information in the web.config and convert your time according to the web.config's timezone.

```
            DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneid); // timezoneid from web.config
            DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```

cstTime is what you want.